# Eclipse c++ : MinGW : Errors when compiling basic Hello World

Tags: c++, eclipse

**Closing:**

Okay, so nobody was able to figure out what my issue was and I can't find any other solutions online, so I ended up giving up on trying to use MinGW and switched back over to Cygwin. Thanks to all for trying though! You can just ignore this post.

**Original Post:**

I am coming from Java mostly and I have used a few other languages however I am completely new to C++. I have installed Eclipse for C++ after loving it for Java (Using Neon for C++). I created the default Hello World just to test my configuration, and I am happy I did. I had to install MinGW and some MSYS tools which fixed most of my issues, however I am still getting some issues.

When compiling the default Hello World.cpp it prints this in the console:

```
22:28:13 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project Hello World ****
make all 
make: echo: Command not found
make: *** [src/Hello World.o] Error 127

22:28:14 Build Finished (took 592ms)
```

I have searched all night and I can't seem to find a solution.
If you have any ideas on what the problem and hopefully a solution is please let me know.

The code generated by eclipse, slightly edited to remove the returned value.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    cout << "!!!Hello World!!!" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Can you also post your code?

Comment: Have you tried doing the solution for : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485941/eclipse-cdt-error-make-src-test2-o-error-127  ?

Comment: @EliSadoff I added my code

Comment: @Bettorun I have not. I just tried it now however to no avail. I can't find echo anywhere in the MinGW directories, and nothing that looks promising in the MinGW installer.